# Firebase Authentication and Facebook Graph Api

Tags: facebook, firebase, facebook-graph-api, firebase-authentication

How can I login a user with graph API then use those credentials to authenticate the same user in firebase or is their any way to get friend list of user with FirebaseUIAuth?

Comment: Do you need continuous access to the Facebook Graph API after sign-in? or is this a one time operation on sign-in?

Comment: i need to retrieve friend list of user time to time so it will need continuous access do tell me solution for both thankyou in advance

Comment: Then you are better off using the Facebook SDK to get the Facebook OAuth access token (you can continuously get access tokens from there) and then sign in with that using `firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(fbAccessToken))`. Firebase only focuses on AuthN and provides an access token only on initial authentication.

Comment: Thank You So Much I will give it a try